# configuring vlan on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vlan

I have bridged `eth0` and `wlan0`, and have given a static ip for the `br0` interface. I wanted to have a `vlan` interface. I did `modprobe 8021q` and I did the following:

```
vconfig add br0 5
ifconfig br0.5 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255 up
```

Then I tried to ping from br0.5 to my router that has 192.168.1.1 ip, which can be accessed via br0.

```
ping -I br0.5 192.168.1.1
```

The replay I get is `Destination Host Unreachable`.

Here is the output of `cat /proc/net/vlan/br0.5`:

```
br0.5  VID: 5    REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1
         total frames received            0
          total bytes received            0
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

      total frames transmitted          329
       total bytes transmitted        20447
            total headroom inc            0
           total encap on xmit          329
Device: br0
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
 EGRESS priority mappings:
```

But the vlan interface can be pinged from other hosts. I pinged the ip of br0.5 (192.168.1.100) form a host on the network and it responded to the pings. So why can't I use br0.5 to reach for other hosts on the network?

EDIT 1:

Output of `iptables -vL`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 823 packets, 215K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                              

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 671 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                                              

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 705 packets, 220K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Do you have any netfilter/firewall rules in the kernel that might be interface specific? what is the output of `iptables -L`?

Comment: Please use `iptables -vL` otherwise it won't specify which interface the rules apply to.

Comment: BTW, what are you planning on doing with this VLAN?

Comment: This sounds like a routing problem. `/sbin/route -n`

Comment: @Zoredache I want to use vlan because I can access internet (WAN) and LAN over one physical network. So br0 will be my LAN interface and br0.5 will be my WAN interface. The machine will do NAT routing.

Comment: @JeffG `route -n` lists the route of br0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did the following: `ifconfig br0.5 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0...`    Then I tried to ping from br0.5 to my router that has`192.168.1.1` ip...

You need to use a separate subnet for the two networks.  So VLAN 1 is currently 192.168.1.0/24, you might want to use 192.168.5.0/24 for your VLAN 5.

Comment: I tried using a a second subnet that could be accessed via br0, br0 was 192.168.0.0/24 and br0.5 was 192.168.1.0/24, and it didn't work.